# Reactivity issue in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Thanks for reading, I am quite puzzled by this reactivity behavior. I had buttons on a navbar, displayed upon condition in the app component (App.vue):

```html
<button
 type="button"
 v-if="loggedIn()"
 @click="logout"
 class="btn btn-outline-light"
>
```

with the associated script:

```js
methods: {
   loggedIn() {
     return !(auth.getUser() == null);
   },
```

here everything works fine and the logout button appears once you log in. Now I am directed to change the design to a sidebar, and create a sidebar component (SideBar.vue) with the exact same html and script. Only issue, the button does not react to the change. the only difference is that the navbar is in the App.vue and SideBar is a component of App like so :

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
        // navbar elements with reactive buttons
      </nav>
      <side-bar />
    </div>
    <main>
     <router-view />
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

Edits :
I tried to use a computed property in the component without success.
I found a way to make it work by passing a property from the app to the sidebar component but I don't like it as I will have to scale probably later. any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: U should use computed properties not methods, its not an reactivity mistake

Comment: I have tried computed as well, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're using a computed, then you should leave out the `()` in the template, i.e. `v-if="loggedIn"`. Also what does `auth.getUser()` do? I hope it's not an async method or something that returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks Terry, If you put the parenthesis vue yells at you anyway, and no auth.getUser() is not async, it just gets the token (jwt) from localstorage and parse it.

Comment: The only difference I can tell is, when I log in, loggedIn() is called when in app.vue, but does not when in SideBar.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in general the structure isn't working out here. It's true like some others said that it's better to use a computed property but this is not the issue right here.

Basically, as soon as the app loads you should call `auth.getUser()`, for example inside your mounted() or created() handler;

```js
// Sidebar.vue or your Root new Vue()
{
    data() {
        return {
            user: null,
        };
    },
    created() {
        this.user = auth.getUser();
    },
}
```

```
<button
 type="button"
 v-if="user"
 @click="logout"
 class="btn btn-outline-light">
```

You can add this to your sidebar component, but it's usually better to handle authentication on the application root component or use Vuex because you often need to know whether or not you're logged in on multiple parts of the app.

If you want to add the created() handler and user variable to your root component you can access it like so;

```
<button
 type="button"
 v-if="$root.user"
 @click="logout"
 class="btn btn-outline-light">
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the design flaw. I will definitely go in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use computed property to bind with v-if like this:

```
computed: {
  loggedIn () {
    return !(auth.getUser() === null)
  }
}
```

More here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 0):

Computed cannot be used here, a computed property will never update, because `return !(auth.getUser() === null)`is not a reactive dependency.

In comparison, a method invocation will always run the function whenever a re-render happens. The solution then, is to re-render the side bar as documented by [Michael Thiessen](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/):

```html
<side-bar :key="loggedIn()"/>
```

Comment: If knowing the status of being logged in becomes necessary throughout more components of your app, though, it might be worth setting a flag or some data that is reactive, so that you can trigger updates through more conventional ways

Comment: Very true, I will do that, I was just frustrated not to understand the behavior though